# How to add 10 more ascending numbers to an array of ascending numbers?

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I'm working with an array called `getListOfYears2` which returns an array of years from 1990-2020. I want to create a new array called `getListOfArrays` which returns an array of years from 1990-2030. Since I am adding 10 more years, I thought of using a for loop. However it is not working and causing my whole page to run out of memory and I can't even use console.log to check what is happening. How can I fix the issues in my code?

```
getListOfYears2(): number[] {
    return Array.from(Array((2020 - 1990) + 1), (_, i) => 2020 - i);
  }

  getListOfYears(): number[] {
    let years = this.getListOfYears2();
    let newYears = years.map(x=>x);
    var i = newYears[newYears.length-1]
    for (i; i<i+10; i++) {
      years.push(i);
   }
    return newYears;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up with out of memory because you used an infinite loop: `i<i+10` this expression will always add 10 to the current value of `i`, so it will never end.

```js
function getListOfYears2()
{
    const years = Array.from(Array((2020 - 1990) + 1), (_, i) => 2020 - i);

    years.sort();

    return years;
}

function getListOfYears()
{
    const years = getListOfYears2();
    const nextYear = years[years.length - 1] + 1;

    for (let i = nextYear; i < nextYear + 10; i++) {
        years.push(i);
    }

    return years;
}

console.log(getListOfYears());
```